# How do i debug my php code inside my html?

Tags: php, html, laravel, xdebug

I'm using Laravel for my project. I wrote some PHP code inside HTML which basically under my `.blade.php` file. I'm trying to debug variable `$highestRow` inside `tbody` tag.

```
<tbody>
   <?php
   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName('Xns');
   $highestRow = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(14)->getHighestRow();
   for($i=1;$i<=$highestRow;$i++){
      $dataC = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getCell('A'.@$i)->getCalculatedValue();
                                                                
      echo"<tr>";
           echo"<td>";
                $name = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getCell('A'.$i)->getCalculatedValue(); 
                echo e($name); 
           echo"</td>";
                for($column = 'B'; $column != $highestColumm; $column++){
                   echo"<td>"; 
                        $name = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getCell($column.$i)->getCalculatedValue();                                                                                                                
                        echo e($name);                                                                  
                   echo"</td>";
                 }                                                                  
      echo"</tr>";
    ?>
</tbody>
```

I tried `var_dump($highestRow)` but my controller is just passing over the breakpoint. I'm looking for some `x_debug()` thing to use for debugging.

All I remember there is some function in Xdebug to debug in such a case.

Thanks

Comment: Dont use the error supression symbol please. and definitely not there as it does NUFIN

Comment: With all the `@` removed do you see any errors. In the error log maybe

Comment: You dont actually ask a question. You also dont tell us what is wrong! we dont have your spreadsheet so basically you are asking us to have a guess.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Here I'm trying to debug my PHP code inside my HTML script

Comment: You cannot debug code if you hide the errors using `@` all over the place

Comment: simple debug tools are `var_dump()` and `print_r()` and `echo`

Comment: So what errors are you getting?

Comment: Out of curiosity: if you are using Laravel, why not also use Blade properly? It would be way easier to use all this sheet reading in your controller

Comment: @NicoHaase I newbie to Laravel. Hence, I'm looking for some help.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, Blade compiles the template into raw PHP code. So you cannot set a breakpoint in the template because that isn't what's actually being executed. Perhaps there's an addon for your editor or IDE (PhpStorm, for instance, can [debug Blade](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2019/05/twig-and-blade-templates-debugging-2/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `xdebug_break()` here. As this function can break any line inside PHP.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that function, helped me debug PHP embedded in HTML, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{{ dd($highestRow) }}` inside your `.blade.php` file.

Comment: Please share more details. The given code does not look like Blade after all, and `dd`  does not help when XDebug does not stop at the proper breakpoint